# Splitting string with '+' seperator into seperate rows and apply aggregation

Tags: mysql, regex, string, aggregation

The data is not static and group of characters separted by + can vary. I want all the characters separated by + to be in row wise and then apply aggregation on the top of it. I am using mysql 5.7.14 in windows.
suppose data is:

```
group   val
a+b     10
a       5
b       6
b+d+c   12
d       13
c+d     12
```

the output should be like:

```
grp_item val
a        15
b        28
c        24
d        24
```

Comment: This is a really bad design. Consider normalizing your table.

Comment: This is not a table but the output of algorithm

Comment: Then you can look at the algorithm logic to give output in a simpler mode. Juggling with your current input will involve lots of string operations, which will be extremely verbose and inefficient.

Comment: This is how i am getting data from customer. I have no control over that

Comment: Then I would suggest you to do these operations in application code (eg: PHP, Java, C, C++, Python etc)

Comment: the data is fed into the db  , i have no other choice except performing query operations in the given mysql db  by the customer . I want to know how in mysql we perform this operation .

Comment: "I want to know how in mysql we perform this operation" You sure you want to do this in MySQL? It is complex but it can be done.

Comment: yes I want to know how is this possible in mysql. but data is not static

Comment: Are you missing a row for only `c` in the above data?

Answer (score 2):

Like i said the MySQL query is complex.. 
The general idea is a MySQL number generator which generates 1 to 10000 so it supports 10000 separated values with the + sign in the group column. 
And it does not matter what data is between the + signs.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   Table1_unique_groups.`group`
 , SUM(Table1.val)
FROM (

SELECT 
 DISTINCT
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Table1.`group`, '+', number_generator.number), '+', -1) AS `group`

FROM (
  SELECT 
   @row := @row + 1 AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) record_1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) record_2    
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) record_4
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) record_5     
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0 
  ) AS init_user_params
) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN 
 Table1 

) AS Table1_unique_groups

INNER JOIN 
  Table1
ON
  FIND_IN_SET(Table1_unique_groups.`group`, REPLACE(Table1.group, '+', ','))

GROUP BY 
 Table1_unique_groups.`group`
```

**Result**

```
| group | SUM(Table1.val) |
| ----- | --------------- |
| a     | 15              |
| b     | 28              |
| c     | 24              |
| d     | 37              |
```

[DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Xd4kiFZLfZRLRFLTEziFu/0)

Comment: I think UNION can be replaced with UNION ALL - will make query marginally more efficient

Comment: "I think UNION can be replaced with UNION ALL - will make query marginally more efficient " it really does not matter that much, what the MySQL optimizer does not tell you is that UNION with or without always requires a temporary table to execute @MadhurBhaiya post of mine https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54184/27070 off C/C++ source analyse of the union part of MySQL.